# Как в Pycharm выбрать интерпретатор из виртуального окружения conda?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

В выборе интерпретатора проекта пробовал указать путь к питону из виртуального окружения, но Anaconda установлена в root и у pycharm нету прав просматривать ее содержимое. Нужно только переустанавливать anaconda в другой каталог?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет переустановить Anaconda на вашем персональном компьютере без root пользователя. Таким образом решится ваша проблема.

Answer (score -2):

Нужно было просто запустить pycharm с рута.

Comment: Нужно было просто переустановить anaconda без рута. Лучше не запускать что-либо от рута без необходимости.